# Classifying some specific type of vector bundles by buildings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, buildings

Assume $C$ is a curve and $p={\infty}$ a point at infinity such that $C\setminus p$ is an affine curve $U=Spec(A)$ and let $R$ be the local ring at $p$ which is a DVR.  Let $F$ be a fixed free module of rank $n$ and $K(C)$ be the function field of the curve. Let $W=K(C)\otimes F$ be an $n$ dimensional $K(C)$ vector space. Let $\tilde{W}$ be the constant sheaf on $C$ corresponding to $W$. Lets $E_F$ be the poset given by the set of all vector bundles on $C$ which are subsheaves of $\tilde{W}$ and such that their restriction to $U$ is the trivial vector bundle $F$. Apparently all these vector bundles are determined uniquely by giving $R$-lattices in $W$. (For each vector bundle the localization at $p$ gives an $R$-lattice in $W$ but there is also a way of constructing a unique vector bundle by knowing the $R$-lattice because of some sort of descent that probably only works for curves.). This implies that the poset $E_F$ is the Bruhat_Tits building (after taking the quotient by the action of $O(p)$) and is contractible.

You can consider the higher dimensional version of this but instead replace the point by a nice hyperplane section $H$ and rename the $C$ to $X$ which is smooth projective variety and preserve every other notation. Is there any nice description of vector bundles on $X$ which are subsheaves of $\tilde{W}$ (defined analogously) and are isomorphic to $F$ on $U$? Or is there such a description for a nice subset of vector bundles for example vector bundles of the form $\oplus O(m_iH)$ which are subsheaves of $\tilde{W}$? Or vector bundle that are also trivial on $H$? is there any way to observe whether $E_F$ is contractible after modding out the action of $O(H)$. (substitute $E_F$ by any of the examples that I provided or you may come up.)